# Generic MUX and DEMUX using Generics

Tags: generics, vhdl, mux

It seems to be solved with the current process:

```
process(sel, X)
begin
    -- set all to 0
    mux_out <= (others => zero);
    -- Set input in correct line
    mux_out(to_integer(unsigned(sel))) <= X;
end process;
```

I will test more cases with the TestBench and write here the results, thanks again to everyone for the help :)

==== PREVIOUS POST =======
I have implemented the DEMUX by following Paebbles example:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.MATH_REAL.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity DeMUX_1toX_N_bits is
  generic (
    PORTS  : POSITIVE  := 4;
    BITS   : POSITIVE  := 8 );
  port (
    sel  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(integer(ceil(log2(real(PORTS)))) - 1 downto 0);
     X    : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BITS - 1 downto 0);
    Y    : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((BITS * PORTS) - 1 downto 0)  
    );
end;

architecture rtl of DeMUX_1toX_N_bits is
  type T_SLVV is array(NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BITS - 1 downto 0);
  signal mux_out : T_SLVV(PORTS - 1 downto 0);
  begin
  gen : for i in 0 to PORTS - 1 generate
    -- connect Output FLAT VECTOR to the correct T_SLVV lines
     Y(((i + 1) * BITS) - 1 downto (i * BITS)) <=  mux_out(i);
  end generate;

  mux_out(to_integer(unsigned(sel))) <= X;
end;
```

The Synthesis Tool tells me " Found 1-bit latch for signal mux_out<3><6>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems."

So to solve this i should assign explicitly '0' to all other output bits?

Thanks again for all the help :) This way of coding is really powerful but also complex :)

================== Previous POST ====

I'm developing a VHDL project (for FPGA) as an university lab.
I'm stuck on the design of a mux and a demux parametrized both in data size and number of ports.
In particular I can't find a way to write a dynamic code (With / Select statements? )

I have in mind something like this :

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity generic_mux is
GENERIC (  inputs: INTEGER := 4;              -- number of inputs
           size : INTEGER := 8);              -- size of each input
Port (
  -- ???  how can i define the input data ports if i don't know the exact number?
);
end generic_mux;

architecture arc of generic_mux is
begin
  -- how can i use the select as an address? The With/Select needs a         
  -- defined number of cases...
  --   ???
end arc;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: I answered this question some time ago on [Core Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/73708/59226) This solution works with VHDL-93 and VHDL-2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using VHDL-2008 it can be done like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package mux_p is
  type slv_array_t is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
end package;

package body mux_p is
end package body;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.mux_p;

entity mux is
  generic(
    LEN : natural;   -- Bits in each input
    NUM : natural);  -- Number of inputs
  port(
    v_i   : in  mux_p.slv_array_t(0 to NUM - 1)(LEN - 1 downto 0);
    sel_i : in  natural range 0 to NUM - 1;
    z_o   : out std_logic_vector(LEN - 1 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture syn of mux is
begin
  z_o <= v_i(sel_i);
end architecture;
```

The `sel_i` should also be `std_logic_vector`, with a length derived from `NUM`, but the above shows the code that is related to the mux.

Usage example of the mux can be:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mdl is
  port(
    a_i   : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    b_i   : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    c_i   : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    sel_i : in  natural;
    z_o   : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture syn of mdl is
begin
  mux_e : entity work.mux
    generic map(
      LEN => 2,
      NUM => 3)
    port map(
      v_i(0) => a_i,
      v_i(1) => b_i,
      v_i(2) => c_i,
      sel_i  => sel_i,
      z_o    => z_o);
end architecture;
```

Comment: Thanks for the MUX , it works fine and is a very short and clear code. I have problems with the DEMUX now, using the same constructs leads to warnings of "latches", i edited my question to explain this.

Comment: Think about what happens with the bits that are not selected for output...   With the current code, these bits are specified to hold the previous value, which requires a latch, and latches generates warnings, since they are usually not desired, but a result of code with unintended behavior, as in your case.  Determine how the non-selected outputs are to be handled, and update the code.  One possibility is to have a default assign of all outputs to 0's or X's, and then override this for the actually selected outputs.

Comment: By using a process it seems solved, the RTL design looks good too :)