# how to make a fully generic MUX in VHDL 93

Tags: vhdl

I would like to synthesis a generic MUX with two generics :

- addressSize (in number of words)
- wordSize (in bits)

This seems fairly easy as per these very similar question : [3459057](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590157/generic-mux-and-demux-using-generics) and [32562488](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562488/variable-number-of-inputs-and-outputs-in-vhdl). The catch is : I must use vhdl 93, and both the answer assumes vhdl 2008 and/or only one of the generics to be a given.

```vhdl
entity Mux is
    generic (
        addressSize : integer := 2;
        wordSize    : integer := 32
    );
    port (
        …
    );
end entity;

architecture RTL of Mux is
begin
…
end architecture;
```

I'm stuck, Indeed, in vhdl 93, I may not use unconstrained std_logic_vector in array:

```vhdl
package common is
    type WORD_ARRAY_type is array (integer range <>) of std_logic_vector;
end package;
```

Which would have let me use both generics has such :

```vhdl
port(
   input : WORD_ARRAY_type(0 to addressSize)(wordSize - 1 downto 0);
   …
);
```

and, of course, I may not define a type in between the generics and ports. The thing is, I must certainly not be the first person who encounters this specific question so I wander : "How would one do this very classic function in VHDL 93 ?"

Comment: The usual way this was done, was to use a 1D slv: `input : std_logic_vector(address_size*wordsize -1 downto 0);` and then slice the input for the appropriate section. Why are you forced to use VHDL 93? All modern tools I am aware of support (at least the paid versions) all support this in VHDL 2008 now?

Comment: not quartus lite 21.1 …

Comment: Hence I suggested all paid versions.

Comment: I agree with Tricky's comment (except the width of the input should be `2**address_size*wordsize`). Just use a wide `std_logic_vector` for the input port and slice it inside a `for i in 0 to 2**address_size-1 loop`.

Comment: I am forced to use VHDL 93 because I do not have the financial means of paying softwares multiple thousands $ a years. Thank you for your proposal regarding slicing, this is very clever and something to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you think you want, however, for a small combinational logic block like this, I would use a function instead and then use overloading to define the a Mux function for each Mux size you need:

```
function Mux (
    sel  : std_logic ;
    A1   : std_logic_vector ;
    A2   : std_logic_vector 
) return std_logic_vector is 
  variable Y : std_logic_vector(A1'range) ; 
begin
  case sel is 
    when '0' => Y := A1 ; 
    when '1' => Y := A2 ;
    when others => Y := (others => 'X') ; 
  end case ; 
  return Y ; 
end function Mux ;
```

Yes it is brute force to develop the package, but once done, it is very simple to use.   Reference the package and do the function call.  And since it is a function, you can chain the outputs together.

```
MuxOut <= Mux(Sel, A, B) and Mux(Sel, C, D) ;
```

If you would like to see something like this in the IEEE standard (which would be a good idea), reach out to me and I can help you get started in participating.

Above, I enforced the sizing to be the same by using the variable.   VHDL-2019 gives us better options.  In fact, it gives us ways to allow the types of A1, ... to be more flexible than just std_logic_vector.

Adding on the @Tricky method, but applying it to subprograms:

```
function Mux (
    Width : integer ; 
    sel   : integer ;
    A     : std_logic_vector 
) return std_logic_vector is 
  alias normalizedA : std_logic_vector(0 to A'length-1) is A ; 
  constant WordStart : integer := width * sel ; 
begin
  return normalizedA(WordStart to WordStart + Width - 1) ; 
end function Mux ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, but I'm confused : wouldn't creating a mux function for each mux size in stark contrast to the notion of a trully generic Mux ? is there no other way ? i would also be interested in getting in contact with you regarding participating in shaping the standard. In what way would like me to contact you ?

Comment: Functions are less work when writing the RTL code.   Both get easier with VHDL-2008 and more so with VHDL-2019.

Comment: I added the @Tricky method to the function call.   Not so excited about having to specify the width on each call, but it is less work than the entity form - until you get 2008 support and it allows the entity ports to be unconstrained (some synthesis tools don't like this)